# COUNT not working in Query with JOIN (SQL)

Tags: mysql, join, count

I tried to add a `COUNT` in my MySQL query, because i need the amount of all rows.

Orginal: 
`SELECT a.*, b.device_name, FROM ( SELECT * FROM qslist ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 500) a JOIN device b ON a.device = b.ID`

NEW:
`SELECT a.*, b.device_name, a.COUNT(ID) AS out FROM ( SELECT * FROM qslist ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 500) a JOIN device b ON a.device = b.ID`

Sadly, the new Query, does not get executed, the following error-message is shown :

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'out FROM ( SELECT * FROM qslist ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 500) a JOIN device b ON a' at line 1**

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`out` is a reserved word in MySQL.  You can escape it or name it something else:

```
SELECT a.*, b.device_name, COUNT(a.ID) AS cnt
FROM ( SELECT * FROM qslist ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 500) a JOIN
     device b
     ON a.device = b.ID;
```

In addition, the `a.` goes next to `id`, not `count()`.

That fixes the syntax error.

This query is unlikely to be doing what you want, because it will return only one row.  The `count()` makes this an aggregation query with no `group by`.  However, your question is about the syntax error, not the correct query for your unstated purposes.  (If you want to fix the query, I would suggest asking another question with sample data and desired results.)

Comment: thanks, but no: " #1630 - FUNCTION a.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual"

Comment: @sgtBear . . . I fixed that too in a subsequent edit.  Sorry for missing it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Your Count will provide you a single row. but the a.* and b.device_name might have muliple rows. to find the count you need to have a separate query that would be better.

Comment: how?, it should count only the rows where the other statements match, because limit is variable, and the query is build automatic, so sometimes there will be a WHERE in it. 

Is it impossible to do a count in php maybe?